# How to move starting node in D3 googleVis Sankey graph

Tags: r, d3.js, google-visualization, googlevis, sankey-diagram

I have drawn a Sankey graph in D3 using the googleVis.  But I want to reposition the nodes on the x-axis based on the number in the name of the node.

i.e

[image: Diagram]

Right now all starting nodes appear on the left side, and they end on the right side.  I want nodes to be able to start in the middle of the diagram.  Can this be done using googleVis?

Comment: It might require hacking a bit with js code, see [this post](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/sankey-diagrams-description-of-d3js-code.html) for dragging nodes on X axis.